How to write a simple SQL query to get the maximum value in "only_full_group_by" mode?
this request is working fine.
SELECT max(original_id) from search_results 

but I need
SELECT max(original_id),created from search_results 

and I get an error
Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'sys.search_results.created'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by  0.047 sec

I do not have database administrator rights and I do not have access to switch "only_full_group_by" mode. How can I fix my request?

You can try to use MAX(original_id) OVER(), but hard to tell without any information what you want to do. Please show some sample data and the expected result. By the way, please never disable the only_full_group_by mode, write correct queries instead.

This table is very simple. There are 2 columns: "id" and "created".
I need to get the maximum value of "id" and the date when it was created.

Add a tag for the dbms used. (only_full_group_by is a product specific feature.)

@user2219963 Thanks for your feedback. It would be better to edit your question with this information and then we can both remove our comments. This improves the clarity of your question.

I.e. provide a complete [mcve]. A 1.8k rep user should know that.

One option is to sort the table descending by the original_id and fetch the first row only:
SELECT
  original_id, created
FROM search_results
ORDER BY original_id DESC
LIMIT 1;

Another standard approach for such tasks is using a subquery:
SELECT
  original_id, created
FROM search_results
WHERE
  original_id = (SELECT MAX(original_id) FROM search_results);

Depending on your data and indices, one of them might be noticeable faster, but both should be fine.
Sidenote: The answer assumes you are using MySQL because the ugly possibility to disable the only_full_group_by usually means this RDBMS is used.
The standard SQL for other RDBMS would be FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY instead of LIMIT 1 in the first query.
Sample here: db<>fiddle
